# C# app fails to load Matlab DLL when running from a shared drive?

Tags: c#, matlab, .net-2.0, caspol, matlab-deployment

I have a C# .NET 2.0 program that calls a Matlab .dll file that I created using Matlab Builder for .NET.  This Matlab .dll file is a wrapper for a m file function that I need to call from my C# program.

Everything works fine when I run this app from my local drive.  However once I copy the app to a shared drive the Matlab dll fails when it's first loaded.

I setup caspol to allow .NET programs to run from shared drives.

Does anyone know what could cause this problem or a tool that I could use to easily figure out what the problem is?

Thanks.

Comment: What does "fails" mean?  Surely you get a better diagnostic?

Answer (score 0):

Try re-adding the .dll from Visual Studio. This is the best guess I can give.